# How to remove a ticks on my dog?

Tags: dogs, ticks

My dog have many ticks, and I don´t know how I can help him. He took gardenal bath and didn´t worke, and also led injection!

Answer (score 0):

Tweezers, and patience. Pluck the little buggers off by the head as detailed [here](http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/pet-advice/how-to-identify-and-remove-ticks-from-your-pet.html). I'd recommend reading the whole thing; it's got a lot of useful do's and don't's for dealing with ticks. Just make sure it's the head you grab and not the body, otherwise the head with stay in your dog and release toxins when it dies.